# Make function to use module it's called from, not module where it's defined

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have a util function, that I want to work with the module from which it is called. Example:

*main.py*

```
import sys
    

def util_func(): # some work with module
    print(sys.modules[__name__]) # __main__


if __name__ == "__main__":
   util_func()
```

It is alright, but when i move this `util_func` to `utils.helpers`, it uses the module it's defined in, not the module it's called from.

```
application
├── utils
│   └── helpers.py
└── main.py
```

*helpers.py*

```
import sys

def util_func(): # some work with module
    print(sys.modules[__name__]) # utils.helpers
```

*main.py*

```
from utils.helpers import util_func

if __name__ == "__main__":
   util_func()
```

As i call this func really often, i don't want to pass the name of the module. Is there any elegant solution?

Comment: I would recommend passing whatever call-site-specific information you need as an argument, rather than trying to make the function figure out where it is being called from. (Otherwise, you'll have to use the `inspect` module to figure that out.)

Comment: What does `util_func()` actually do? Maybe there's a better way to accomplish the same thing. Be wary of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: Why is it so hard to pass the name of the module? `util_func(__NAME__)` isn't that bad.